# From screen coordinate to svg

Tags: svg

I have a xml file that contain point, polygon, polyline in screen coordinate. For example:

```
<!--StartGraphics-->   
<rectangle>
<reportElement x="480" y="30" width="270" height="137"/>
</rectangle>

<line direction="BottomUp">
<reportElement x="693" y="112" width="7" height="36"/>
</line>
<line>
<reportElement x="598" y="128" width="96" height="20"/>
</line>
<line>
<reportElement x="581" y="125" width="17" height="3"/>
</line>
<line>
<reportElement x="500" y="108" width="81" height="17"/>
</line>
<line direction="BottomUp">
<reportElement x="500" y="70" width="6" height="38"/>
</line>
<line>
<reportElement x="506" y="70" width="24" height="3"/>
</line>
<line>
<reportElement x="529" y="74" width="78" height="19"/>
</line>
<line>
<reportElement x="607" y="93" width="60" height="13"/>
</line>
```

How could i convert this file to svg coordinate to display my shape in viewport of svg?
Thank.